# Insert into array translated value from NSLocalizedString

Tags: xcode, nsarray, nsdictionary, nslocalizedstring

I have a plist with an array of dictionaries.

example:

```
items: (array)
    item0: (dictionary)
        Label: (string)
        Img: (string)
    item1: (dictionary)
        Label: (string)
        Img: (string)
```

using NSLocalizedString, the labels are translated.

With this code, I put everything in a dictionary, and after into an array.

```
NSString *myFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"plist"];

NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:myFile];

NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[dict objectForKey:@"Items"]];
```

How do I place into the array, however, the value directly translated, and not the key?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
 NSMutableArray * arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: [dict allValues]];
```